# Full width issue part 2

Tags: jquery, css

I'm seem to have some excessive horizontal scrolling on the right side of my page.

I've deducted that it's something to do with script I have on the top of my site – when I remove it the issue resolves itself.

Just to give you an idea of what I'm hoping to achieve; I want the image at the top to span 100% width of the browser but keep the type centred.

When you first visit the site you'll get a good idea of what I'm talking about.

http://cargocollective.com/btatest

Thanks in advance

Michael

**EDIT**

Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // The social div 
    var $socialDiv,
        // The social div's height 
        socialDivHeight = 560,
        currentSocialDivHeight = socialDivHeight;


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $socialDiv = $('.social');
        $socialDiv.css({
            'background-image': 'url(http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/563655_324264884301748_471368753_n.jpg)',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-attachment': 'fixed',
           'background-size' : '110% auto',
            'height' : socialDivHeight + 'px',
            'margin-left' : '-100%',
            'margin-right' : '-100%',


        });
    });


    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        //Get scroll position of window 
        var windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 

        var newSocialDivHeight = Math.max(0, socialDivHeight - windowScroll);

        if (Math.abs(newSocialDivHeight - currentSocialDivHeight) < 1)
            return;

        $socialDiv.css({
            'opacity' : 1 - windowScroll / 400
        });

        currentSocialDivHeight = newSocialDivHeight;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey  now you can change your code if yes than please create a jsfiddle link and put the your html and css code .......

Comment: Please put your code what you've tried?

Comment: Yah, jsfiddle would help ... hard for me to see what's causing it as is. Though you could try `html,body { width: 100% }`

Comment: @Vins I've just edited my original comment with the offending script.

Answer (score 0):

The `<div class="social" style="background-image: …;">` is causing the scrollbar.

You are effectively creating an element that is 2160px wide (incl. margins) and wonder why you have a horizontal scrollbar?

You have:

```
.project_content { width: 720px; }
.social {
    /* implied with = 100%, since this is a block element */
    margin-left: -100%; /* add 720px on the left */
    margin-right: -100%; /* add 720px on the right */
}
```

But your goal is to have the `.social` with a width of 100%. To achieve that you could re-order your HTML-structure or take the element out of the "normal" flow by assigning `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` to it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm going through a noob spell when it comes to Jquery.

Comment: @user1522319 There is not a single line of jQuery in my answer; just plain CSS is your problem…

Comment: When I add a '.social {position: relative;}' to my CSS there's still a scroll issue, 'absolute' completely removes the '.social'.